# Parsing through large files, counting the number of unique strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm parsing through a ton of comma delimited files. Each file contains thousands of rows, each row has the same amount of fields, populated with similar or different strings. I'm at a point where I've parsed through the files, and saved each row as a Python list. I'm looking for ideas on how I could parse through all of the captured lists in python and, for example, return the number of unique strings in item[1], or whatever item i'd like in the lists.

How should I go about this? Thank you for reading my first post! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re looking to be concise, you could utilize [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
num_unique_in_first_column = len(collections.Counter(map(operator.itemgetter(0), rows)))
```

---

**Bonus:** For gigantic amounts of data, where not only may the rows not fit in memory, but neither does the set of unique values, and you’re okay with estimates of the number of unique values, you can use [HyperLogLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog). You almost certainly don’t have enough data to justify using one, but I find it to be an interesting digression.